# android Error no Gradle signed APK

Tags: android

Bom dia, quando clico pra gerar o apk assinado, ele da o seguinte erro:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> Job failed, see logs for details

o que poderia ser ?

Comment: Esse erro dá geralmente quando as versões do SDK, Build Tools e Plugin version divergem no que se refere a compatibilidade. Tenta ver se está tudo ok e depois da um clean e make project.